The system cannot find the path specified after running npx <package name> command on cmd in windows
The system cannot find the path specified. I got this error while running the command on cmd npx . I have done possible thing to solve this problem
I have tried npx huzaifa-atm-machine on window's cmd. This is my package which is been published on npm. But, When I am trying to run this command through the npx command it shows me an error. When I search this package name through npm search it shows me the package that it is exists on npx
